# Using CSS, how can align smaller text on right on the same baseline?

Tags: html, css

What change should I make to this:

```
<span style='font-size:400%'>left</span>
<span>right</span>
```

( https://jsfiddle.net/5z3ec48r/60/ ) to get 'right' to align right, but retain its vertical baseline alignment with 'left'?

i.e.

[image]

This:

```
<span style='font-size:400%'>left</span>
<span style='float:right'>right</span>
```

( https://jsfiddle.net/xx5ob2m1/) need not apply:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into a common container, like a `div`, to which you give these settings, using flexbox (the width can be anything):

```
.x {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ht4zb79s/1/

Comment: PS I find this works with span replacing div, and since span seems more appropriate given the small content, I'll use span.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float and try the following:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;    
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 48%; /* or whatever */
}

span + span {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to have to set a width since it might not suit the content in general.

Comment: You don't really need the width, that was just for the example